# How get data in scroll (inginitive scroll, lazy loading)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to get scroll how in https://www.seznam.cz/?

This is my code, it works but it add data at bottom. I want to add data 500 PX to bottom?

```
var flag= 5;
$(window).scroll(function(){    
    var heigh_scroll= $(window).scrollTop();
    if( heigh_scroll == $(document).height() - $(window).height() ){    
    //  console.log('ajax');     
        jQuery.ajax({          
            url:'site/ajax-bottom',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'offset':flag,
                'limit':1,
            },
            success: function (data) {

               $('.timeline__list').append(data);
               flag+=5;    
            },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //errorPosition();
            jQuery('.restult').html('Please enter again');
            console.log('Error' );
        }
    });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var callAPI = true;
$(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
   alert('end of page');
   //----call your function here ---
   if(callAPI){ funCallAPI(); }
  }
});
function funCallAPI(){
  callAPI = false;
  ....
  ...
  ajax_success_response:{
     callAPI = true;
   }
}
```

`-10` indicates how far away from end of page user must be before function executes. This gives you the flexibility to adjust the behavior as needed.

[check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/wQfMx/)

Note that : `ajax_success_response` will be real `$.ajax` function.

Comment: thank for your answer, but i try change my code this way, if I do that I have problem with ajax request. it do more than 1. screen http://joxi.ru/EA4ZgExiDM5zKm

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically you need to set flag, when to go for next api call, otherwise it will keep calling function again and again. Hope you can get it.